# Upload larger images using UploadedFile extension for Yii2

Tags: file-upload, yii, yii2, image-uploading

i want to upload images to the server and i try with success using a code that i see in a youtube video from [DoingITeasyChannel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKG24GJpZRA).

But, it works with lightweight (150 Kb) files; i'm trying to upload a 3.1 Mb image and the program breaks. 
This is my code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Images();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');

        $fileName = $model->category.''.date('U').'.'.$model->file->extension;
            // save the path in db
        $model->location = '/yii_advance/frontend'.'/web/images/'.$fileName;


        $model->file->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/web/images/'.$fileName);

        // crea y guarda el thumbnail de la imagen subida
        Image::thumbnail(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/web/images/'.$fileName, 220, 120)
            ->save(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/web/images/thumbs/'.$fileName, ['quality' => 80]);

        $model->thumbLocation = '/yii_advance/frontend'.'/web/images/thumbs/'.$fileName;

        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
}
else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

NOTE:
I've tested without the thumbnail part, and i think the solution can be a way to run the "$model->save()" and the "return" after complete the upload.

Comment: check your php.ini file for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, like user1852788 said, the solution was in my php.ini file.
I had to change the upload_max_filesize attribute was limited for 2M.

Thanks.